# Unwrapping error in Optional value in file path

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
func openPDFFromInternet(www: String){
        let serwerUrl = ApiConstans.fullPath + "" + www
        let url = NSURL(string: www)
        print("the url = \(url)")
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string : www)!)
    }
```

www has value: "

```
/Users/imac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2B19B93-A0AD-46DF-923F-E18DD76EAC96/data/Containers/Data/Application/A37F7B0E-3B67-42E8-B616-5C3066F5653F/Documents/eng/PDF/MyFile RostiBites2015-ENG new_OK-prev.pdf"
```

Print return me nil.

When I run this code I have error:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Does anyone know repair it? I have file in this path.
I can't rename my filename

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Comment: The issue here is due to the fact that the filename has spaces included.. Removing the spaces in the filename will return a value for url

Comment: Its also true that there are invalid escape sequences used specifically '\g' just before '/PDF'

Comment: On a different note, are you not getting warnings that you are not using the constant serwerUrl? Also use URL instead of NSURL in second line

Comment: if you must have the space in the file name you can url encode the filename string and then use that

Comment: Then you must url encode the filename and use that string

Comment: edit the question.. dont post it in comments

Comment: @triff don't add irrelevant tags, especially after they've been removed through edit for a reason. Swift version tags should only be used when asking about a change/issue specific to a Swift version, however your question is not related to any changes between Swift3 and 4, so you shouldn't add those tags.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Thank you for you info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is clearly a file system URL – indicated by a leading slash – so the API `URL(string:` is wrong. You have to use `URL(fileURLWithPath` which percent escapes space characters implicitly.

```
func openPDFFromInternet(www: String){
    let serwerUrl = ApiConstans.fullPath + "" + www
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath : www)
    print("the url = \(url)")
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Or if the URL can be local or remote a more robust way

```
func openPDFFromInternet(www: String){
    let serwerUrl = ApiConstans.fullPath + "" + www
    if www.hasPrefix("/") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath : www)
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    } else {
        guard let escapedString = www.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed),
        let url = URL(string : escapedString) else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: this code starts correctly, but does not open the pdf file in the default system program

Comment: Actually that's another question  Is the file URL valid?

Comment: Please check if the URL is valid at **runtime**.

Comment: yes, I have this path for example: file:///Users/imac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2B19B93-A0AD-46DF-923F-E18DD76EAC96/data/Containers/Data/Application/E25C2467-1047-4C49-B8C4-75373D99ED1F/Documents/en/PDF/Folder%20A4-R2015-ENG%20new_OK-prev.pdf - when I copy this and paste to Firefox - it opens correctly without any errors

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by the `URL` having invalid characters, namely spaces in it. You need to encode the URL to remove the invalid characters.

```
let localUrlString = "/Users/imac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A2B19B93-A0AD-46DF-923F-E18DD76EAC96/data/Containers/Data/Application/A37F7B0E-3B67-42E8-B616-5C3066F5653F/Documents/enb\\g/PDF/MyFile RostiBites2015-ENG new_OK-prev.pdf"
if let localEncodedUrlString = localUrlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlPathAllowed) {
    let localUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: localEncodedUrlString)
}
```

Your function name is quite misleading, since the value of `www` in your question is clearly a local file path, so either change the function name or if it really is supposed to open files from remote URLs, change `URL(fileURLWithPath: localEncodedUrlString)` to `URL(string: localEncodedUrlString` and use optional binding to safely unwrap the failable initializer.